# How to save color to SharedPreferences Android

Tags: android

I am trying to save color to `SharedPreferences` using

```
public static void saveChannelImageColor(int color) {
    saveInt(CHANNEL_ID1, color);
}

public static int getChannelImageColor() {
    return getInt(CHANNEL_ID1, 0xff0000ff);
}
```

But when i am trying to get the color it is giving error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer at
>   android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:239)

Comment: are you sure, your color value is saving as int value in your preferences? because your default value **0xff0000ff** is not integer.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code with saving and reading from SharedPreferences?

Comment: Don't save color  as an int but as a string and then retrieve it as string and do the needful processing.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty much self explainatory you are assigning an int value to the string. You need to do one of the following

1. Save color as String

   ```
   public static void saveChannelImageColor(int color) {
       saveInt(CHANNEL_ID1, String.valueOf(color));
   }

   public static int getChannelImageColor() {
       return getString(CHANNEL_ID1, "0xff0000ff");
   }
   ```
2. Whereever you are using getChannelImageColor it is returning an int so you save/use/assign it to an int variable.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, but hope it helps someone.

Kotlin code:

> set color in Preference reference

```
lateinit var mPreferences: SharedPreferences
lateinit var mEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor   
// initPreferences with Context   

mEditor.putInt(KEY_COLOR_PRIMARY, R.color.colorPrimary)
mEditor.commit()
```

> get and set as background

```
view.background =  mPreferences.getInt(KEY_COLOR_PRIMARY,
```

R.color.colorPrimary))